# Is it possible to to create an auto complete feature using JS using the yfinance library?

Tags: yfinance

I am creating a Flask web application for fun and learning, and I would like to see if I can create a search.html that on input of string will auto complete the ticker symbol and show it as a dropdown list.

I think that the most straightforward way of doing so is to have a variable with all tickers for a specific exchange e.g. NYSE.

Is it possible to extract the tickers for a specific exchange using yfinance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to extract all the symbols from a stock exchange using yfinance. There are some threads about it, and a few libraries, check this link:

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/26162/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-yahoo-finance-stocks-symbols?newreg=4f53f54f75aa4816ac33b78a3be02f7b